# Laravel newbie and external (Moodle) database

Tags: mysql, database, join, laravel, external

I'm trying to read from external Moodle database in Laravel Eloquent, to display all users that are teachers, and put them into a dropdown list inside a form.

I have Teacher model containing:

```
class Teacher extends Eloquent
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $connection = 'moodle';
    protected $table = 'mooddle_user';

    public function Task()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Task', 'id');
    }
}
```

I can return all users just simply by using lists method, but the problem is that the info whether the user is indeed a teacher or not is not stored in this table. Instead I have to use a few `JOIN` commands to retrieve teachers.

I'm wondering how can I execute this command inside the model, to use it simply in the dropdown of the Task view. Task model, accepts teacher_id - foreign key.

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.firstname, u.lastname
FROM moddle_user u
JOIN moddle_user_enrolments ue ON ue.userid = u.id
JOIN moddle_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN moddle_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
JOIN moddle_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid AND r.shortname = 'editingteacher'
WHERE e.status = 0 AND u.suspended = 0 AND u.deleted = 0
AND (ue.timeend = 0 OR ue.timeend > NOW()) AND ue.status = 0
```

I tried running it as Raw query through model but no luck, because it locks inside a `moddle_user` data table and so I am unable to use `JOIN` with other tables.

I know I could've tried to create 4 additional eloquent models, but since I only need this one query to return all teachers, there could be another way around this.

Any idea and suggestion greatly appreciated =).

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#running-queries

Comment: I did check it through already before, but didn't found anything useful... After reading it slowly i managed to pull out some additional info which I could use. Really need to be more precise next time. Thanks.

Comment: You could modify the model so to achieve something like a default scope:  http://laravel.io/forum/02-13-2014-eloquent-model-default-scope.  Since there are so many joins and aliases are all over the place, I personally would simply create a function that queries the User model and incorporates the JOINs and WHEREs you listed above.

Comment: Interesting idea, I have managed to create a default scope in the model to return only teachers. But in the controller im unable to list them (the list is empty). There is no SQL error but when i DD i got the following result: `... mdl_role_assignments`.`roleid` = `mdl_role`.`id` where `mdl_role`.`shortname` = ? and `mdl_enrol`.`status` = ? and `mdl_user`.`suspended` = ?' (length=510)` Any idea why are there shown question marks instead of real values? If I manually replace them and run SQL query in database i get the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've found out there is thing called DB::connection that you use before the methods like select, statement etc.

For other newbs like me, I share the solution for top example:

```
$teachers2 = DB::connection('moodle')->select(DB::raw("SELECT DISTINCT u.firstname, u.lastname
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid AND r.shortname = 'editingteacher'
WHERE e.status = 0 AND u.suspended = 0 AND u.deleted = 0
AND (ue.timeend = 0 OR ue.timeend > NOW()) AND ue.status = 0"));
```

Now if only was there a way to use the result as a whole model (I only need teachers, never whole users).

Edit:

I've fixed the whole problem elegantly by using global scopes "http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#global-scopes". This way my model always works on array of teachers.

Regarding those question marks it just means that there will be a value presented when Laravel runs it.